# How to get all Tree Leaf nodes of tree in GOJS

Tags: jquery, gojs

I want to fetch all tree leaf node

Below code I used to fetch but it's not worked

```
myDiagram.findNodesByExample({ isTreeLeaf:true }).each(function (n) { 
    myDiagram.findNodeForKey(n.data.parent).collapseTree(); 
});
```

> Note: I don't have property `isTreeLeaf` in my node data. I want it from
>   node property

Is there any easy way to fetch leaf node?

Comment: Currently I'm looping all nodes to find TreeLeaf Node Which is take long process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myDiagram.nodes.filter(n => n.isTreeLeaf).each(n => console.log(n.key));
```

Comment: Yeah I should use filter. Thanks :)